# Leaflet: Uncaught TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add markercluster into leaflet.

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

My header file include:

```
   script(src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js')
   link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/MarkerCluster.css')
   link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/MarkerCluster.Default.css')        
   script(src=/javascripts/leaflet.markercluster-src.js')
```

But I keep getting the error of :  L.markerClusterGroup is not a function

I am not sure why I get that error.

Answer (score 10):

This was a simple import mistake with angular, changing imports to the following, resolves this issue:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';

// Compile & run = OK
private myClusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

Tested using Angular 7, leaflet 1.6.0 and leaflet.markercluster 1.4.1

Comment: for your first line I did use instead
import * as L from 'leaflet/dist/leaflet';
and it's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss a quote in your declaration

```
script(src='/javascripts/leaflet.markercluster-src.js')
```

Comment: I actually have like what you said, but it still doesnt work

Comment: The script is likely not found. Did you check your javascript console ?

Comment: Yes. It is in there.

Comment: I dont know why, but when I put "var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();" inside the window.onload = function(){}. it doesnt show the problem anymore.

Comment: maybe it has to do with the functions you are using script() and link(). Why are you not using <script> and <link> elements ?

Comment: I am using pug. I was following some tutorial when I start learning how to use nodeJS. (I am new to nodeJS). They use Jade (now it is called pug). script() and link() is just syntax of pug.

Answer (score -4):

Try

```
var markers = new L.markerClusterGroup();
```

instead of

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
```